# How to get a row number from a table in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, row-number

How can I learn whether a particular name is present in my table, and and in which row (row number) it is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your database structure but here is the simple examples

```
Cursor c = database.query(TABLE,new String[]{_ID,NAME},NAME + "in(" + queryName + ")",null,null,null};
```

now this will return those rows whose name are match with the `queryName` and `queryName` contains like `('abc','pqr')`, now in the second argument I have pass the column name first is `ROW ID` and another is `NAME` now go through the iterator.